# taking a laurent series and writing in terms of a specified interval z is restricted to

Tags: complex-analysis

I want to show that when $0 < |z| < 4$, then $\frac{1}{4z-z^2} = \frac{1}{4z} + \sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}$ $\frac{z^n}{4^{n+2}}$.

My first observation is that the bottom can be factored which sets it up nicely for partial fractions. After doing partial fractions, I obtain $\frac{1}{4z} + \frac{1}{4(4-z)}$. Now from here I am a little unsure how to finish the problem up.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how you advance. You need to use the geometric series

> $$ \frac{1}{1-t}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}t^k,\quad |k|<1. $$

$$ \frac{1}{4z} + \frac{1}{4(4-z)}=\frac{1}{4z} + \frac{1}{16(1-z/4)}=\frac{1}{4z}+\frac{1}{16}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{z^k}{4^k}=\frac{1}{4z}+\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{z^k}{4^{k+2}}. $$